# Why are the elements of the Cyclic Group with Generator $\langle 3 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z_{15}}$ {0, 3, 6, 9, 12} and not {1, 3, 9}

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I'm going through Charles Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra which was recommended as an simple introduction.
In the Chapter about Cyclic Groups he mentions that the cyclic subgroup generated by $\langle 3 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z_{15}}$ is $\left \{0, 3, 6, 9, 12\right \}$.

I thought I understood that a cyclic group is all powers of its generator? 
Which would lead me to $\mathrm{3}^0$, $\mathrm{3}^1$, $\mathrm{3}^2$

I think I am misunderstanding something badly here.
Could someone please explain to me?

Thank you!

Comment: The operator is addition, not multiplication.

Comment: Hello @DonThousand, thank you for answering. Does this mean that the elements of a cyclic group can be other than powers of the generator?

Comment: The elements are the powers of the generator. But here, $x^3=x+x+x=3x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Power" in the context of groups means repeated application of the group operation to a single element. In *general*, one usually denotes the group operation multiplicatively, hence the word "power" makes sense. However, in the group of $\Bbb Z_{15}$, there *is no multiplication*. There is only addition. Addition is the group operation, and the element that would, in the general framework, be denoted as $3^4$ is actually $3+3+3+3 = 12$.

Many people like to have an entirely parallel vocabulary for dealing with additive groups. In that case, they would say that "The cyclic group generated by $3$ consists of all *multiples* of $3$", and instead of writing $3^4$, they would write $4\cdot 3$, where $4$ is still an integer, and $3$ is still an element of $\Bbb Z_{15}$ (it's harder to see the difference between $4$ and $3$ this way, but it's there).

P.S. Even if we were to consider the "actual" multiplicative powers of $3$ in $\Bbb Z_{15}$, you missed two: $3^3 = 27= 12$ and $3^4 = 81 = 6$.

Comment: Hello, thank you this makes it very clear. And now I even noticed my modular arithmetic mistake. I had thought of 27mod15 to be 3 (3 away from 2*15), but the remainder is actually 12. Same with 81. Thank you this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hint  :

Here the operation is addition, not multiplication. $$a^5 = a+a+a+a+a$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me. I figured it's addition it says multiples of 3 in the book. But this is exactly why I am having trouble understanding it. Does this mean that the generator is only giving the elements to work with and the groups operations adds the other elements?
Edit

To quote the book: G may consist of all the powers of a and nothing else, in that case G is called a cyclic group.

Comment: can we write $5a$ insted of $a^5$?

Comment: @user199590 and gaurav: looks Arthur gave a very good explanation already:)